# Changing select to non-native menu after docuement ready with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a select in a web app written using jQuery Mobile, and I want to to add `data-native-menu="false` to it after the page has rendered.

I have the following example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="cont">
    <select id="sel">
        <option>test1</option>
        <option>test2</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sel").attr("data-native-menu", "false");
    $("#sel").selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

the above in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzuc8/3/).

The attribute is added fine, but after having tried everything I can think of with `.selectmenu()`, `.trigger('create')`, `.selectmenu("refresh", true)` etc. the select isn't changed from using the native menu, to using jQuery Mobile's.

Obviously there is something I'm missing, but what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it before the page is created `pagebeforecreate` event.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
  $("#sel").attr("data-native-menu", "false");
});
```

In jQuery Mobile, use jQM [events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) instead of using `.ready()` as it's not recommended.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G9Gmc/)**